# vba listobject CopyFromRecordset

Tags: excel, vba

How to populate data from a recordset into a listobject?
The code below is not completely working:

```
oCN.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=SRVSQL;Database=TEST;"
oCN.Open
Dim sqlString As String
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE"
oRS.Open sqlString, oCN

With Feuil3.ListObjects("TableArticles")
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

    ' This make a 91 error
    Call .DataBodyRange.CopyFromRecordset(oRS)
    ' This copy data into sheet, not into listobject
    Call Feuil3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset(oRS)
End With
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are always deleting the `.DataBodyRange` first, you can use the `.InsertRowRange'.

```
With Feuil3.ListObjects("TableArticles")
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
    .InsertRowRange.CopyFromRecordset(oRS)
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found the solution.
Just resize the listobject to fit the content:

```
With Feuil3.ListObjects("TableArticles")
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

    Call .Range(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset(oRS)
    Call .Resize(Feuil3.UsedRange)
End With
```